# Closed form solution for divided differences $f[a_1, a_1,...,a_1, a_2]$

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

Let's consider divided difference:

$$f[a_1, a_1, \dots,a_1, a_2]$$

where we have $n$ occurrences of $a_1$ and function $f$ is $n$ times differentiable on segment $K = \mathbb C$. I want to find closed form solution for function $f$.

My problem is that when we consider $n = 1$ we have:

$$f[a_1, a_2] = \frac{f(a_2) - f(a_1)}{a_2 - a_1}$$

And for $n = 2$:

$$f[a_1, a_1, a_2] = \frac{f[a_1, a_2] - f[a_1, a_1]}{a_2 - a_1}$$

but here, the problem is that divided difference $f[a_1, a_1] = \frac{f(a_1) - f(a_1)}{a_1 - a_1} = \frac 0 0$ is problematic to calculate.

Could you please give me a hand in solving this problem?

Comment: First, I expect you mean a solution involving $f$ and its derivatives, rather than a closed form solution for $f$, which is given... Second, the answer to how to deal with $f[a_1,a_1]$ is likely explicitly dealt with in the definition of the notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can understand $f[a,a,...,a]$ as the limit of $f[a,a+h,a+2h,...,a+nh]$ for $h\to 0$. It should be almost intuitive that this evaluates to
$$
f[\underbrace{a,a,...,a}_{n+1~{\rm times}}]=\frac1{n!}f^{(n)}(a).
$$
For your expression one gets thus
$$
f[\underbrace{a,a,...,a}_{n~{\rm times}},b]
=\frac{f[\overbrace{a,a,...,a}^{n-1},b]-f[\overbrace{a,a,...,a}^{n}]}{b-a}
=\frac{f[\overbrace{a,a,...,a}^{n-1},b]-\frac1{(n-1)!}f^{(n-1)}(a)}{b-a}
$$
which iterates out to
$$
=\frac{f(b)-f(a)-f'(a)(b-a)-...-\frac1{(n-1)!}f^{(n-1)}(a)(b-a)^{n-1}}{(b-a)^n}.
$$
So the left side is the coefficient of the remainder term of the Taylor polynomial in $a$ of degree $n-1$.